# How do I make a C function and preprocessor macro available to several Objective-C classes?

Tags: objective-c, c, import, c-preprocessor

I have a **C** function and a macro:

```
double degreesFromRadians(double radians) { return (radians * 180.0 / M_PI ) ;
#define FPROUND(doubleA, doubleB) round( (doubleA) * pow(10.0,doubleB))
```

which I use in one of my Objective-C model classes. I also would like them to be available in my unit Test class for some additional tests not related to the model class.

Not wanting to duplicate the code, I tried to put it into a separate `MyAppMathFunctions.c` file and to `#import` it into the model class.

Now building the app with Xcode (version 7.0) fails with a linker error:

```
duplicate symbol _degreesFromRadians in MyAppMathFunctions.o  and ...modelClass.o
```

Needless to say, because of that failure, I didn't go on to putting the `#import MyAppMathFunctions.c` into my unit test class, as I had originally planned.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Moving this code to a C file is not a good approach, because C files are not meant to be included in other translation units. Doing this creates duplicate symbols, but more importantly, it creates confusion among the readers of your code.

One approach to solving this problem would be placing the definition into a header file with an `inline` modifier, and then providing a definition of the function in exactly one translation unit by using the `extern` declaration:

appmath.h:

```
#define FPROUND(doubleA, doubleB) round( (doubleA) * pow(10.0,doubleB))
inline double degreesFromRadians(double radians) {
    return (radians * 180.0 / M_PI );
}
```

appmath.c

```
#include "appmath.h"
extern double degreesFromRadians(double radians);
```

This way the body of your function would remain available to the compiler for inlining in all translation units, and there would be no duplicate symbols when your code is linked.

Comment: Looks like you've mixed up the .h and .c files. Most people put the function definition in the .c file and the declaration in the .h file.

Comment: @Caleb When you inline with C99 inlining rules, definition and declaration "switch places" ([more details are here](http://www.greenend.org.uk/rjk/tech/inline.html)).

Comment: @dasblinkenlight So does the `inline` statement in your example serve to optimize the code because it is such a small function, or is it for the linking process ? (I just read "inline functions" in Wikipedia.)

The reason I ask is because I have a few more math functions to put in my appmath.h , some of which are longer than one line. I am concerned that if the compiler inlines them everywhere, the compiled code might get large. Whilst I am only interested in being able to access these functions from a couple of separate classes.

Comment: @WS I chose `inline` because the function is so small. For bigger functions you do it the other way around, i.e. what Caleb said: the header file gets `extern double bigFunction(double arg);`, and the .c file gets `double bigFunction(double arg) {/* body goes here */}`